# Fluid dynamics: conversation of momentum for wind turbine

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am in my first fluid dynamics year. I was doing some calculations for a wind turbine:

[image]

In the first task, I converted the non linear output velocity into a linear one.
So I can assume that the input velocity is $u_\infty$ and the output velocity is $\overline{u_e}$

I used a cylindrical control volumne around the turbine with radius R to calculate the force that acts on the wind and got to the following point:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum F 
&= \rho\int_{\partial A} (\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n})\cdot \vec{v} \ dA \\
&= \rho \left(-u_{\infty}^2 \cdot \pi R^2 + u_e^2 \cdot \pi R^2 +\color{red}{\Delta \dot{m} \cdot v_{\infty}} \right)
\end{align}
$$

I highlighted $\color{red}{\Delta \dot{m} \cdot v_{\infty}}$ because I did not come up with it. I was struggeling with the momentum of the mass that leaves my cylindrical control volume at the side.

I've tried deriving this myself but didn't get anywhere close. I would appreciate if someone could explain how it is derived.